# C on windows, code to copy files not working

Tags: c, windows, copy, cmd

I have this piece of code; it works when you directly write the arguments to `system()`, and doesn't work if you pass the arguments to it. Any help please?

```
char dest[100];
char file[50];
char dir[100];

printf("Enter source path: ");
scanf("%s", dir);

printf("Enter filename: ");
scanf("%s", file);

printf("Enter destination path: ");
scanf("%s", dest);

system("move \"c:\\users\\putty.exe\" g:\\ \n" );  /* <--works        */
system("move \"%s%s\" %s", dir,file,dest);         /* <--doesn't work */
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
char dest[100];
char file[50];
char dir[100];
char command[300];
printf("Enter source path: ");
scanf("%s", dir);
printf("Enter filename: ");
scanf("%s", file);
printf("Enter destination path: ");
scanf("%s", dest);
sprintf(command,"move %s%s %s", dir,file,dest);  
system(command);
```

Comment: If the three path elements are 100, 50 and 100 characters long, the command string should probably be longer than 250 characters.  Ideally, you'd modify those `scanf()` formats to specify the limits (`"%99s"` and `"%49s"`) to avoid overflows, and consider using `snprintf()` or `snprintf_s()` rather than `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 3):

The `system()` command is not a `snprintf()` substitute.  You would need to use `snprintf()` and then `system()`:

```
char command[1024];
...
snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "move \"%s%s\" %s", dir, file, dest);
system(command);
```

Or, given that you're on Windows, you can use `snprintf_s()` instead of `snprintf()`.  You might also note that if the user does not leave a backslash at the end of the `dir` value, then the last component of the directory and filename are combined.  You should probably use:

```
snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "move \"%s\\%s\" %s", dir, file, dest);
```

Although the Windows kernel is quite happy with slashes in the path name, the command processor is less so.  Since you are not calling the operating system directly but rather the command processor to run a program, you need to use backslashes, I believe.

Note that your compiler should have been telling you that you were not calling `system()` correctly.  The header is `<stdlib.h>` and that states that the function takes just one argument.

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.22.4.8 The `system` function
>
> Synopsis
>
> ¶1 `#include <stdlib.h>`
>
> `int system(const char *string);`
>
> Description
>
> ¶2 If string is a null pointer, the `system` function determines whether the host
>   environment has a command processor. If string is not a null pointer, the `system`
>   function passes the string pointed to by `string` to that command processor to be
>   executed in a manner which the implementation shall document; this might then cause the
>   program calling `system` to behave in a non-conforming manner or to terminate.

If your compiler was not telling you that you were misusing `system()` with your second call, or not complaining that `system()` was declared before it was used, then you need to turn up the warnings level on your compilation, or get a better compiler.  If it was warning you, you need to pay attention to what it says. Remember, the compiler knows more about C than you do.